# Website thumbnail on other websites

Tags: html, icons, frontend, favicon

I just added my personal website http://oatmeeel.com/ to my Linkedin. It appears that there is no thumbnail/icon showing on my LinkedIn (https://ca.linkedin.com/pub/oat-wongsajjathiti/63/55b/967)

How do I add some sort of an image (like favicon) to any links to my website from other websites. Sorry if I'm being unclear. Here is an image of my issue.

Thank you
[image: Screenshot of my Linkedin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Linkedin uses three open graph protocols, one of them being image to scrape an image to use from your website. Scrolling through your source code I didn't see one. Try adding `<meta property="og:image" content="http://URLTOYOURIMAGE" />` to the  of your website and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It didnt work for me though.

Comment: Also: (From LinkedIn)The first time that LinkedIn's crawlers visit a webpage when asked to share content via a URL, the data it finds (Open Graph values or our own analysis) will be cached for a period of approximately 7 days.

Comment: also @NitsornWongsajjathiti you've set your metadata content property to `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.oatmeeel.com" />` the URL needs to point to an image. Example: <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.oatmeeel.com/img/myimage.png" />

Comment: Thank you @DavidLuby. I have made the changes and hopefully it will work after the cache is cleared. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Awesome! Let me know, I'll look at other options if it doesn't work!